# Open TCP connection in nginx ingress

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, clickhouse

I get a problem on opening TCP connection via nginx-ingress.

So the goal is I want to open ***Clickhouse*** TCP connection on port 9000 on my Kubernetes Cluster which using Nginx-Ingress.

So far, I can open 9000 TCP port connection on the nginx-controller, however, I still can not hit the Clickhouse server with tcp protocol. Im still believe this caused by the nginx/ingress side.

Clikhouse installation is working fine to hit by `port-forward` and `http` protocol on 8123 port is open successfully via ingress

Here are some information about the service on my cluster:

```bash
kubectl -n ingress-nginx get svc                                                     
NAME                                 TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)                                    
ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   an.internal.ipx  an.external.ip   80:31714/TCP,443:31594/TCP,9000:32033/TCP   
ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      an.internal.ipy  <none>           443/TCP
```

How I do this?

I only did this on my `values.yaml` of helm deployment

```yaml
# values.yaml
ingress-nginx:
  tcp:
    9000: "test-clickhouse-operator/clickhouse-test-chi-speed:9000"
....
....
```

In other words, I have a clickhouse installation in namespace `test-clickhouse-operator` with service name `clickhouse-test-chi-speed`

```bash
kubectl -n test-clickhouse-operator get svc
NAME                            TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)                         
chi-test-chi-speed-simple-0-0   ClusterIP      None             <none>           9000/TCP,8123/TCP,9009/TCP      
clickhouse-operator-metrics     ClusterIP      an.internal.ipxx <none>           8888/TCP,9999/TCP              
clickhouse-test-chi-speed       LoadBalancer   an.internal.ipyy an.external.ipyy 8123:31889/TCP,9000:32457/TCP
```

Note: `an.external.ipyy` is not reachable to outside of the cluster.

And last, here are my ingress for the domain:

```bash
# ingress-subdomain-clickhouse-native.yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-test-clickhouse-native
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: clickhousenative.staging.mydomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: clickhouse-test-chi-speed
            port:
              number: 9000
```

When I try to hit this [clickhousenative.staging.mydomain.com](http://clickhousenative.staging.mydomain.com) via browser, it will return:

```bash
Port 9000 is for clickhouse-client program
You must use port 8123 for HTTP.
```

However, when I hit with `clickhouse-client -h clickhousenative.staging.mydomain.com` it get failed.

Is there any step I miss here guys?  Any advice will be helpful as well, since I have no any resource that I can follow now, Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You need allow TCP port expose and balancing for nginx ingress controller, look documentation for examples https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/

Comment: I have followed the steps precisely. I successfully opened the port on the controller side as mentioned in my question. The port 9000 is accessible; however, I am still unable to establish a connection to ClickHouse using the ClickHouse client

Comment: For additional context, when I expose my application using port-forward and access the exposed port through a web browser, it displays the same information as when I access the exposed subdomain. Could this serve as evidence that Nginx has correctly exposed the TCP, and the issue may lie on the ClickHouse side?

Comment: do you understand this error message?

you can't access to 9000 port via HTTP
use `clickhouse-client`for access via TCP native protocol

Comment: Nope, that is why I asked here, But I guess this `clickhouse-client` should connect via ingress-nginx-controller_ip:9000 rather than the `clickhousenative.staging.mydomain.com` ? both of them is not working anyway

Comment: which error show `clickhouse-client -h clickhousenative.staging.mydomain.com`?

Comment: > ingress-nginx-controller_ip:9000 < why do you need use ingres ip to connect INSIDE kubernetes? use standard service name for connection inside kubernetes and don't use ingress